# Is calling C++ code from Swift more "expensive" or slower than calling C code?

Tags: c++, ios, c, swift

I have never tried Swift but my research suggests that callling pure C code is simpler than calling C++ code.

Does this mean that there are associated performance impediments and, if so, how significant are they?

Comment: What prevents you from trying it?

Comment: I'm at a "Research" stage. I don't have access to a Mac or Xcode just now. I am trying to architect a cross-platform software solution so I'm seeking helpful answers to assist in my design choices to minimise the amount of potentially wasted "trial and error"...

Answer (score 2):

Swift has no C++ interop at present. That means you either have to create a C or Objective-C++ wrapper around your C++ classes in order to bridge them to Swift.

In practice this is very unlikely to have a performance impact - it'll add another method call using VTABLE dispatch that in turn calls the C++ method. It does, however, create a lot more manual work that needs to be done in order to use your C++ code-base in Swift.

Comment: Thanks Jasper. I'm more concerned about performance penalties than extra coding effort at this stage so that's helpful info.